# Why is this commit that sets the RSA public exponent to 1 problematic?

Tags: security, cryptography, salt-stack

I saw [this commit](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/commit/5dd304276ba5745ec21fc1e6686a0b28da29e6fc) in [SaltStack](http://saltstack.com/) on Hacker News, but I don't understand exactly what it does or why the original version was a cryptography error. (I also don't know a lot about how the specifics of cryptography work, either.)

```
-    gen = RSA.gen_key(keysize, 1, callback=lambda x, y, z: None)
+    gen = RSA.gen_key(keysize, 65537, callback=lambda x, y, z: None)
```

Can someone elaborate why the choice of "1" was replaced? And why is "65537" better?

Comment: In short, when e=1 then d=1 and encryption is the identity map, i.e. no encryption.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You've essentially asked three questions:

- What is this code doing?
- Why is `1` bad?
- Why was it replaced with `65537`?

It sounds like you don't have a lot of cryptography background, so I'll try to fill in some of the gaps there as well.

### What is this code doing?

To understand why the original value of `1` was a broken choice, you have to understand a little bit about how [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) works.

RSA is a *cryptosystem* -- a way of performing key generation, encryption, and decryption -- so that you can send messages securely to other people. RSA is a member of a class called ***public-key cryptosystems***, because the key that you use to encrypt messages is ***public*** and can be freely known by everyone. The key you use to decrypt messages enciphered with your public key is secret and known only by you, so we call it a ***private key***.

If you imagine padlocks and keys as the analog to public keys and private keys, you can see how this might work with real-world messages:

- Bob gives Alice a padlock (his public key) and keeps the key to the lock (his private key).
- Now, if Alice wants to send a Bob a message, she puts a message inside a box, puts his padlock on a box, and sends him the box.
- Only Bob has the key, so only Bob can unlock the padlock and get inside the box.

To actually generate the key, RSA needs three important numbers:

- "N", the product of two very large prime numbers p and q
- "e", the "public exponent"
- "d", the "private exponent"

A big part of the security of RSA comes from the fact that it should be very difficult to figure out what `d` is, given `N` and `e`. The public key in RSA consists of two numbers: `<N,e>`, while the private key is `<N,d>`.

In other words, if I know what Bob's padlock looks like, it should be **very difficult** to reverse-engineer a key that will open Bob's padlock.

### Why is `1` bad?

`1` is a bad choice because it makes **very easy** to reverse-engineer a key that will open Bob's padlock, which is the opposite of what we want.

The problematic section in full looks like this:

```
def gen_keys(keydir, keyname, keysize, user=None):
    # Generate a keypair for use with salt
    # ...
    gen = RSA.gen_key(keysize, 1, callback=lambda x, y, z: None)
```

This is a Python fragment which generates a RSA key with `e = 1`.

The relationship between `N`, `e`, and `d` is given by:

```
d*e = 1 mod (p-1)(q-1)
```

But wait: if you pick `e = 1`, as SaltStack did, then you have a problem:

```
d = 1 mod (p-1)(q-1)
```

Now you have the private key! The security is broken, since you can figure out what `d` is. So you can decrypt everyone's transmissions -- you've made it so that you can trivially get Bob's key given his padlock. Oops.

It actually gets worse than that. In RSA, encryption means that you have a message `m` to transmit that you want to encrypt with the public key `<N,e>`. The enciphered message `c` is computed as:

```
 c = m^e (mod N)
```

So, if `e = 1`, then `m^e = m`, and you have `c = m mod N`.

**But if `m < N`, then `m mod N` is `m`.** So you have:

```
 c = m
```

The enciphered text is the same the message text, **so no encryption is happening at all!** Double oops.

Hopefully it's clear why `1` is a bad choice!

### Why is `65537` better?

65537 seems like an unusual, arbitrary choice. You may wonder why, for instance, we couldn't just pick `e = 3`. The lower `e` is, the faster encryption becomes, since to encrypt anything we have to execute:

```
 c = m^e (mod N)
```

and `m^e` can be a very large number when `e` is large.

It turns out that 65537 is mostly for compatibility reasons with existing hardware and software, and for a few other reasons. [This Cryptography StackExchange answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/impacts-of-not-using-rsa-exponent-of-65537/3113#3113) explains it in good detail.

With a suitable random padding scheme, you can pick almost any odd integer higher other than 1 without affecting security, so `e = 3` is otherwise a choice that maximizes performance.

Comment: 65537 = 2^16 + 1, which offers certain advantages in performance. Setting e to a number as small as 3 can lead to slight vulnerabilities in performance. 65537 is somewhat arbitrary but it's also what the NSA recommends for government cryptography.

Comment: “Now you have the private key!” – but how do I get from `N` and `e` (the public key) to `p` and `q` (needed to calculate `d` using `1 mod (p-1)(q-1)`)?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert `(p-1)(q-1)` is equal to `φ(N)`, so you get `d = 1 mod φ(N)`. You don't need to know `p` and `q`, just `N`, which is made public (only `d` is secret).

Comment: But isn’t computing `φ(N)` hard? [This answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/3275) says: “Factoring and computing the Euler totient function are known to be equivalent for arbitrary numbers […]” So does it really matter that we can (theoretically) compute `φ(N)` if it’s just as hard as factoring N to get p and q?

Comment: The implication is that SaltStack, by using 1 as the exponent, was not encrypting data at all. Is this true?

Comment: That's correct. Raising a number (in this case, m) to the power of 1 doesn't change it.